# Moving the cursor to the end of line after a find and replace in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have written my own plugin for an auto-correct feature in CKEditor 4, it allows you to type @abc for instance and it will replace this with "as easy as one two three" plus a space character and put the cursor after the space.

This is the javascript code from the plugin that updates the string:

```
var s = editor.getSelection();
var bookmarks = s.createBookmarks(true);
var data = editor.getData();
var replaced_text = data.replace(typedchars, Suggestions + '&nbsp;');
editor.setData(replaced_text); 
var range = s.getRanges()[0];
range.moveToBookmark(bookmarks[0]);
range.select();
```

It works perfectly on my local machine but as soon as I put this code into production I get an error on the line - **range.moveToBookmark(bookmarks[0]);** and the cursor goes to the start of the line.

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParent' of null
```

and points to this line in the ckeditor.js file

```
setStartBefore: function(a) {
  this.setStart(a.getParent(), a.getIndex())
},
```

From what i can see both versions of ckedtor.js are the same and no other files have changed.

There is nothing on Google to suggest a reason, so hoping someone here might have an idea.

Cheers

Comment: an update - the source code in CKEditor looks like this 

<p>easy as one two three&nbsp;<span id="cke_bm_75C" style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></p>

it is not moving the end if the line nor is it removing the bookmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified above to this and now it works perfectly

```
editor.focus();    
var storeCursorLocation = function( editor ) {
bookmark = editor.getSelection().createBookmarks( true );
};
var restoreCursorLocation = function( editor ) {
    editor.getSelection().selectBookmarks( bookmark );
};
storeCursorLocation( editor );
var data = editor.document.getBody().getHtml();
var replaced_text = data.replace(typedchars, Suggestions + '&nbsp;');
editor.document.getBody().setHtml( replaced_text );
typedchars = '';
restoreCursorLocation( editor );
```